# How can I check currently logged user in user authentication on Mean Stack (Node.js + Mongodb)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a login system with tokens. When logging in, it checks whether such a user exists, doesn't have information about current user during the login session. What's the easiest way to check it and send response to frontend?

Routes:

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  if (token === 'null') {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');
  if (!payload) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  req.userId = payload.subject;
  next();
}
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  let userData = req.body;
  let user = new User(userData);
  user.save((error, registeredUser) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      let payload = { subject: registeredUser._id };
      let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secretKey');
      res.status(200).send({ token });
    }
  })
})
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let userData = req.body;

  User.findOne({ email: userData.email }, (error, user) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      if (!user) {
        res.status(401).send('Invalid email');
      } else
        if (user.password !== userData.password) {
          res.status(401).send('Invalid password')
        } else {
          let payload = { subject: user._id };
          let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secretKey');
          res.status(200).send({ token });
        }
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a middleware to retrieve the token from the Authorization header and retrieve the userId from there, the middleware could look something like this:

```
const decodeToken = (token) => {
    return jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey', (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return decoded;
    });
};

const authorize = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'UNAUTHORIZED'});
    }
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'UNAUTHORIZED'});
    }
    const decodedToken = decodeToken(token);
    if (!decodedToken) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'UNAUTHORIZED'});
    }
    req.userId = decodedToken.subject;
    next();
};

module.exports = authorize;
```

Hope this helps you, if not, I hope you find your answer :)

**EDIT**

To use the middleware you only need to add it to your route, I´ll leave you an example with a get request:

```
const authorize = require('../middleware/authorize');

router.get('/someroute', authorize, (req, res) => {
  // authorize will verify the token and attach the userId to your request
  // so to use it you'll only need to call req.userId
  // something like this
  console.log('current logged user id', req.userId);

  // YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I'm just a beginner and I don't understand your code very much. I have function to verify token, but I have no idea how could i use your code. I'd rather edit the token when I save it than rewrite it. It seems very complicated :(

Comment: I edited my answer, hope that clarifies your doubts

Comment: I used token to do that, but not with your solution, I return data of current user alongside the token, but thanks!